# List Update on new Entry for all Users

Tags: javascript, browser, page-refresh

I have a problem right now that I am facing and I dont know what to do.

I have written a program where users can add themselves to a certain list. This list is displayed to each user and the whole thing works in the browser. How does it work that the list is automatically updated for all other users when a user enters the list. I know only the way to query the data e.g. every second. But I know that this is not good. I am relatively new to the subject and would appreciate your answer.

I have a REST API server running via the NPM package "express" which fetches the data from a MySQL database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check  [this](https://github.com/supabase/realtime) out, or maybe if your project is just for fun, then try using a NoSQL Database like Google Cloud Firestore, it has built in real-time fetching and updating on client side

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.